# Setting onClickListener for a ListView item using a ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-context

I have an `InfoListAdapter` that uses the following code to populate views in the list:

```
    public InfoListAdapter(final Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.populateViews(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I am wondering how I can follow this `ViewHolder` pattern and still add an `onClickListener` that will launch another activity `DetailListActivity` when clicked. My stragey was to make the `mListener` change using the existing `populateViews` method.

Needless to say it does not work. I think part of the problem here is that since `mListener` is null when I set the `onClickListener`, that reference is retained even after I change the value of the `mListener`. But the deeper question is how *do* I set something like this up, where I can use the `ViewHolder` pattern and let `populateViews` do the decoration (in terms of adding a listener to the click action)?

```
class ViewHolder {
    private TextView mTextViewDisplayName;
    private OnClickListener mListener;
    private Context mContext;

    public ViewHolder(final View view) {
        mTextViewDisplayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_displayname);
        view.setOnClickListener(mListener);
        mContext = view.getContext();
    }

    public void populateViews(final Info infoItem) {
        mTextViewDisplayName.setText(infoItem.displayName);

        mListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view0) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
                mIntent.putExtra(EMService.INTENT_EXTRA_DETAIL_VIEW_SOMEPARAM, 0);
                startActivityForResult(mIntent, 0);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent activity/fragment that houses your ListView you can implement OnItemClickListener and handle your clicks there. This way you don't have to assign a click handler for every single view you instantiate.

Ex. Lets say you have a ListActivity class named MyListActivity (I'm so creative)

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EMService.INTENT_EXTRA_DETAIL_VIEW_SOMEPARAM, 0);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: And how do I bind that listener onItemClick to my Activity's ListView?

Comment: To be clear, I tried `this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this)`, but is that the ideal way to go about this? Why do I have to even bind it when I've implemented interface `OnItemClickListener`? Shouldn't it automatically do that?

Comment: @Luksprog I definitely did `extend ListActivity` and `implement OnItemClickListener`, and added the override `(void) onItemClick`, but it only seems to work when I bind it using `this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this)`. If I don't have that line nothing happens with an item click.

Comment: @jshin47 You do need call that line to associate the listview with the callback. You're doing it right :)